# The loop will skip the macro do while loop when y is entered

Tags: c

I need help regarding this... the problem in my c is when I execute this program and when  I want to repeat the roll, the roll will not be displayed from 2nd time onwards... what do I do? I dont know what to do to fix this.. got stuck here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int i, a, n, z;
  char player[5][150], b, c;
  float ave, total, f1, f2, f3;

  total = 0;
  ave = 0;
  printf("\nPlease enter number of players : ");
  scanf("%d", &a);

  for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
  {
    printf("\nEnter player %d's name : ", i + 1);
    scanf("%s", &player[i][150]);
  }

  printf("\nChoose the amount of dice used : ");
  scanf(" %d", &n);

  do
  {
    for (z = 1; z <= a; z++)
    {
      printf("\n\t%s\n ", player[z]);

      if (n == 1)
      {
        do
        {
          f1 = 1.0 + 6.0 * ((float) rand() / RAND_MAX);
          printf("\nRoll : %.0f\n", f1);
          total = f1;
          printf("Total : %.0f\n", total);
        }while (f1 == 6);
      }
      else if (n == 2)
      {
        do
        {
          f1 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
          f2 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
          printf("\nRoll : %.0f,%.0f\n", f1, f2);
          total = f1 + f2;
          printf("Total : %.0f\n", total);
        }while (f1 == f2);
      }
      else if (n == 3)
      {
        do
        {
          f1 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
          f2 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
          f3 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
          printf("\nRoll : %.0f,%.0f,%.0f\n", f1, f2, f3);
          total = f1 + f2 + f3;
          printf("Total : %.0f\n", total);
        }while (f1 == f2 && f2 == f3);
      }
    }
    printf("\nRoll again ? (y/n) = ");
    scanf("%s", &b);
  }while (b == 'y');
  printf("\n");

  ave = total / n;
  printf("Average : %.2f\n\n", ave);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &player[i][150]);` should be `scanf("%149s", player[i]);`

Comment: you also should ensure that `a` is not larger than 5. `for (z = 1; z <= a; z++)` should be `for (z = 0; z < a; z++)`.

Comment: when asking/handling the number of players,  1) need to include the '5' upper limit in the prompt.  2) need to check the user entered value to assure it is in the range 1..5  otherwise the user could enter a (for instance) 6 and the loop that is retrieving the player names will write beyond the bounds of the array, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: 3) if the user were to enter 'a' when ask for the number of players, then the scanf() would fail (return 0) without changing the garbage in the 'a' variable.  I.E. always check the returned value from scanf() and family to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when asking/handling the number of dice, 1) need to include the '3' upper limit in the prompt.  2) need to check the user entered value to assure it is in the range 1..3 other wise the final for loop will not properly handle the summing of the dice.  (suggest re-writing the final for loop to handle any number of dice.  3) always check the user entered number of dice to assure it is in the valid range 1...3 and check the returned value from the scanf() to assure the operation was successful

Comment: after the code to input the 'y'/'n' from the user,  the reality is the use can input 'y' (lower case) to stay in the game or ANY other input to exit the program

Answer (score 4):

First thing is

```
scanf("%s", &b);
```

should be

```
scanf("%c", &b);
```

And you have to flush your stdin for your `do while` to work.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

The portable way to flush `stdin`

Comment: Mixing input ignoring blank (`%s%d%f`) and input processing it (`%c fgets`) always causes trouble to beginners... Just look the number of questions about that on SO :-(

Answer (score 0):

`%s` reads a C string, that is a null terminated char array. The shortest string containing `'y'` is a 2 character array: `"y"` or `{ 'y', '\0'}`.

So you should change `char b;` with `char b[2];`, and use it that way:

```
    scanf("%1s", b);
}while (*b == 'y');
```

You current code writes (at least) a null after character `b` invoking undefined behaviour: anything can happen after that. But `scanf("%1s", b);` only reads first non blank character in `b[0]` and puts a null in `b[1]`: correct.

But IMHO, never mix input ignoring blank (space, tab, end of line) (`%d%s%f...`) with input explicitely processing them (`%c`, `fgets`), unless you are sure why you do it. So I will not advise you to use `scanf("%c", b);`

Answer (score 0):

regarding this line:

```
scanf("%s", &b);
```

variable 'b' is a character, so it must be read as a character.

```
scanf(" %c", &b );
```

note: leading space in format string so leading white space will be skipped over